# How to lazy evaluate commands in a shell for loop

Tags: bash, shell, lazy-evaluation

I want to implement a fallback mechanism: if one command fails, try the next or the next (or the next). There may be any number of commands to process in the same manner. The following implementation (simplified, error handling should be better, but that's not the current matter) runs all commands before evaluating the for loop contents. How do I make this lazy?

```
f() {
  for message in $(cmd0) $(cmd1) $(cmd2) # cmd1, cmd2 should evaluate lazily
  do
    if [ $? == 0 ]
    then
      echo "ok: $message"
      return # exit early
    fi
  done
  echo "error: $message"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your commands, `cmd0`, `cmd1` return `0` on successful run and non-zero on failure you can just do

```
f() {
    for cmd in cmd0 cmd1 cmd2; do
        if "$cmd"; then
            echo "ok: $message"
            return
        fi
    done
}
```

See an example running commands, `true`, `false` which return codes `0` and `1` respectively,

```
f() {
    for cmd in false true; do
        echo "running command $cmd"
        if "$cmd"; then
            echo "ok: $message"
            return
        fi
    done
}
```

Running it,

```
f
running command false
running command true
ok:
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do just

```
f() { cmd0 || cmd1 || cmd2; }
```

which evaluates `cmd1` only if `cmd0` fails, and `cmd2` only if both `cmd0` and `cmd1` fail.